# Inconsistent behavior of pyserial and rshell when executed in a .py file

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial, micropython, lego-mindstorms

I am trying to program my lego mindstorms inventor robot using python and [this](https://pypi.org/project/mindstorms/) pypi package. It basically uses rshell to communicate with the lego robot that is running micropython. Here is the code that I am trying to execute.

```
from mindstorms import Hub
hub = Hub()
motor = hub.port.E.motor
print(motor)
motor.run_for_degrees(270)
```

When I run this code line by line in the python shell in the terminal everything works as expected. The motor turns. However, if I put this in a .py file, I get this error. `rshell.pyboard.PyboardError: ('exception', b'', b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>\r\nAttributeError: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'run_for_degrees\'\r\n'`
Seems like the issue is that the motor is not being detected by the brain when I run the script in a .py file.
I made another script for diagnostics. It is sending messages directly to the robot without using the pypi package.

```
board = Pyboard(device)
board.enter_raw_repl()
print(board.exec_("import hub;print(hub.port.A.info())"))
```

The result is "None". The brain by itself is detected because commands such as `print(board.exec_("import hub;print(hub.info())"))` run successfully. When I am trying to get any information about the port, the result is None, which makes me believe that the connected motor is not detected by the .py file. Again, if I simply run all this code in the python shell it works perfectly. I am confused by this irregular behavior.

Here are the steps that I took to troubleshot this(none of them worked):

- Tried to run a .py file from the terminal using exec() function, and still get the error that the motor is None.
- Checked that the python version of the shell and the version of the python that is running the .py file is the same.
- Running this script on different machines.
- Reinstalled lego mindstorms firmware and ensured that the latest version is running.

Any suggestions why this would this problem occur?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to wait a few seconds after the initialization of the Mindstorms brain before performing any kind of motor initialization.

```
from mindstorms import Hub;
import time
hub = Hub();
time.sleep(2)
print(hub.port.A.motor);
hub.port.A.motor.run_for_degrees(30);
```